# Option element bigger than select box - how to get the options list to expand to the left?

Tags: html, css

The problem I am currently facing is really hard to describe, but maybe you can the idea from the following screenshots. The setup is a select box (width limited via css) and some option elements inside. If one option's width is greater than the width of the select box, the whole thing gets rendered like this by default:

[image: Select box expanding to the right]

And this is how I want it to be displayed (the red box being the options):

[image: Select box expanding to the left]

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:** Here is a fiddle with the markup I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/dCmZ2/

Comment: Can you include the HTML from your current version?

Comment: @JohnFx I made a fiddle with the markup, see the link in my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have much control over a browser's render of a select box. Just think about mobile devices like the iPhone. Here the select list takes over half the phone screen and is custom rendered. If you want this level of control then you will need to roll your own custom select box.

```
div:hover ul { display: block; }
div ul { /* custom css for placement */ }
<div>
   <ul><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul>
</div>
```